# Usage of CompletableFuture's exceptionally method in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, completable-future, kotlin-interop

I'm trying to handle CompletableFuture exceptions in Kotlin, but I'm not able to figure out how to supply the appropriate parameters. So, for example, I have:

`CompletableFuture.runAsync { "sr" }
  .exceptionally{e -> {}}`

but then the compiler complains `Cannot infer type parameter T`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite a tricky case which becomes tricky because of some Kotlin magic :)

The direct solution to your problem would be the following code:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync {"sr"}
   .exceptionally({e -> null})
```

The detailed explanation goes here:

The `runAsync` method accepts a `Runnable` which means after execution it will return `Void`. The function passed to `exceptionally` method must match the generic parameter of the `CompletableFuture` so in this particular case, you need to help a compiler by returning `null` explicitly.

So the following will compile without problems:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync {"sr"}
 .exceptionally({null})

CompletableFuture.runAsync {}
 .exceptionally({null})
```

In the first case, the "sr" String will simply be ignored and not returned since the `runAsync` accepts a `Runnable`.

You probably wanted to do something like:

```
 CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {"sr"}
   .exceptionally({"sr_exceptional"})
```

or:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {"sr"}
  .exceptionally({e -> "sr_exceptional"})
```