# How to get a Void value in Kotlin for returning functions that requires it

Tags: java, kotlin, completable-future

I am using `CompletableFuture` from `java9.util.concurrent` package in Kotlin, and it has a method `exceptionally` that receives a function `(Throwable) -> Void!` that is called when I call `completeExceptionally`.

If I try a call like this:

```kotlin
myCompletableFuture.exceptionally { exception ->
    doSomethingWith(exception)
}
```

The IDE complains about that I am returning `Unit` and I should be returning `Void!`.

I have tried also the following:

```kotlin
myCompletableFuture.exceptionally { exception ->
    doSomethingWith(exception)
    val returnValue: Void by Delegates.notNull()
    returnValue
}
```

But when executed, it throws a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` with the message `Property returnValue should be initialized before get`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property returnValue should be initialized before get.
    at kotlin.properties.NotNullVar.getValue(Delegates.kt:62)
```

Should I avoid using `CompletableFuture`s at all, or there is a workarround os some kind to deal with this problem?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593837/usage-of-completablefutures-exceptionally-method-in-kotlin) help/

Comment: Wow, I could have sworn I had already tried returning `null`. Simply putting `null` in the last line inside the lambda does the job. Thanks!